# Building a StartUp and moving from PHP to Ruby at the same time?

Tags: php, ruby, sinatra

I am about to build the backend for my startup, which will be mainly offering a REST service, but HTML content will become available later. I am an experienced PHP developer and was thinking about building it in PHP first, but many people try to convince me to switch to Ruby. I would love to, but I have the following concerns:

- I want to create a prototype quickly, learning a new language costs me a lot of time.
- Right now I do not have a second developer who has Ruby expertise, so if I am stuck searching for a bug somewhere, it is worse than being stuck in PHP, where I know a bunch of people to get assistance from.

Some of the arguments people are making in favor of Ruby are:

- It is easy to find good developers for Ruby, because the language itself is a filter.
- Using a framework like Sinatra would speed up my development time drastically
- Ruby is fun

What would you do?

Answer (score 2):

The questions are :

- do you prefer fun, or efficiency ?
- do you have time to wait before being efficient ?
- why not just recruit a good php developer ?

  - Even if there are bad developers on the market, there are also good developers
  - And I should add it's not that hard to see if a developer is good or not.
- you say *language is a filter* ; don't you think it'll be enough of a filter to just make things hard when it comes to finding a ruby developer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're betting your money on this startup, take the road that you know. Getting to market quickly and having a support structure may be a lot more important than switching to a fun language.

Comment: This was the route I wanted to take first, even though it sounds less exciting. I will get my excitement from other sources like user feedback and exploding registration numbers ;)Good to know others feel alike. Thanks for your advice!